# C# and Powershell turning up short on LastLogon property

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADUserLastLogon -Username (Username)
```

in powershell returns

```
12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
```

Similarly, in C#, a

```
PrincipalContext
```

search will pull up a "Null" result when the AuthenticablePrincipal property

```
.LastLogin
```

is addressed.

However, when Active Directory is opened to the Attribute Editor tab of this user, it shows a date of 5/11/2017 12:05:58 PM.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a different property I should be looking for to check the last logon date?  I've actually done some hefty research on the internet about this, and everyone says this message only occurs when the user has never logged on before.  This clearly isn't the case, and I'm confused why nobody else has addressed this yet.

I'd also like to mention that this only affects certain Windows Servers.  I have tested this on 4 different Windows Servers, and 2 are working as they should.  Is it possible that there is an administrative setting that is preventing this from working?

EDIT:  lastLoginTimestamp attribute is also returning that same bogus "Never Logon" or that date I mentioned in the past.  Attempted the script found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Active-Directory-user-246f17c7) and received "Never Logon".  Active directory's attribute editor begs to differ.

Thanks in advance,
Bill

Comment: The `lastLogon` attribute is not replicated between domain controllers.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm running it on the main domain controller as far as I can tell.  I've tried it on both of the servers owned by this client.  Are you saying it won't work on either of them?

Comment: I am saying that the `lastLogon` attribute is not replicated. If you want to retrieve the most recent `lastLogon` time for a user that is up-to-date, you will have to connect to each and every domain controller. The alternative is to use the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute, which _is_ replicated. The `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute is not updated at every logon, so it has some limitations (it was designed to detect stale objects). Some web searching on these attributes should help clear this up for you.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart So, I intend to place this C# program on the main domain controller that is used.  The issue is that 90% of the users are coming up with "null" lastLogon.  If it was just a replication issue, I would think that at least on one of the two servers I would be getting more than 10% feedback.  I've looked at the lastLogonTimestamp, and I'm not that happy with the results.  I'm wondering why on the one set of Windows servers it works fine, and the other set it does not.  I'm testing this on multiple sets of independent domain controllers.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have just confirmed that the 'lastLogonTimestamp' is also returning with that value.  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Active-Directory-user-246f17c7 is the script I am running in powershell.  it returns '12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM'.

Comment: This is not a programming/development question. I recommend asking on serverfault.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I appreciate the recommendation.  I'll mark that as an answer.